# My 16x4 LCDs are printing out junk

Tags: pcb, lcd, software

I have checked every other post on this, and no solution currently works and need an opinion.

I have an LCD (P/N: FC1604A01-RNNYBW-66SE) that is being powered by 5 V and is controlled by a 3.3 V signal that is translated up via a TXB0108 on a breakout board.

There are 0.5 m long harnesses on either side of the logic level converter. I had some success early on with slightly shorter harnesses.

Basically the output is garbage. It sometimes appears to have some of the words or characters that I would expect, but it is in no way reliable. It is also likely to change if I touch the LCD. I am wearing a wrist strap as well. My main wonder is if it is noise on the harnesses, and an early thought was some sort of grounding issue. Has anyone else had the same issue with their LCDs?

[image: The LCD with an example of the rubbish]

Comment: So what code you use to drive it? How fast bus? Or rather, have you probed the signals with oscilloscpe? Or even more, why not start by schematics and diagrams how everything is connected. Although I suspect the TXB0108 is completely wrong component for being in the middle with half a meter of wires on both sides.

Comment: I've had a similar issue a few years ago ... from what I remember, it was a combination of bad programming and bad wiring

Comment: This needs more pictures of how everything is wired. Are grounds connected on both sides of the voltage translator? Did you put a decoupling cap on it (both power supplies)? And of course... the voltage translator specs a 500 picosecond risetime, so... why not use more "civilized" chip like 74HCT245?

Comment: Have you made sure to tie any unused data lines to ground?

Comment: @vir Ground unused data wires of what? MCU? TXB0108? LCD? Better be sure it is the correct thing before suggesting it.

Comment: Garbage in = Garbage out.  Without the code or schematic or distance between transmitter and receiver, this is opinion.  Send the same character and see what you get.  Send all 1's, all 0's.  Shorter is better is a clue.  Try shorter while implementing this comment.

Answer (score 3):

Check threads on the TXB parts.  They're trash for this sort of application; they should only be used on very limited use cases, with short lead length and common CMOS I/Os.

It may also be signal quality on your wiring or harnesses.  Please show photos of wiring and layout.

Use extra ground wires, e.g. ribbon cable with every other wire grounded; use ground plane on boards; and use source termination resistors or ferrite beads on anything long enough to need it (for most CMOS output pins: a foot or so length).  Use bypass capacitors on supplies.